# How do I make this menu black and remove underline?

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm creating a website for a future clothing company. I don't have much experience with coding, so bear with me if it's a bit sloppy. I just want a full black line to go across the page and make the horizontal menu black and remove the underline.  How do I do this?

```
<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="280" height="81"> <li><a href="#">
    <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="30" height="81">  
         <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="30" height="81">
    <li><a href="#">Photography/Art</a></l
```

Comment: underline where? Please don't post a big block of code where only a few lines are relevant, you should always create a reduction of your problem. You have to show due diligence before asking a question. It doesn't look like you've tried to solve the problem on your own

Comment: If that's an image you can't just use CSS to change it. CSS is for styling HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a style for the anchor tags and changed the width of the hr tag to 100%.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<STYLE>
<!--
 a:hover{color:#000000;}
-->
</STYLE>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<img border="0" src="http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/2628/rf3h.png" alt="Vealed" width="280" height="81">

<!-- This hr tag needed a 100% width, not 60% -->
<HR COLOR="black" WIDTH="100%">
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<!--Added a style here and referenced it in the class atribute of the anchor tags in the global nav. -->
<style>

    .navLink {
    color: #000000;    
    text-decoration: none !important;}

ul
{
list-style-type:none;
font-size: xx-large;
font-family: helvetica neue;
font-weight: lighter;

margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li
{
display:inline;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>


<ul id="nav" >

<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="280" height="81"> <li><a href="#">
    <li>
        <!-- see the class attribute here -->
        <a href="#" class="navLink">Men</a>
        </li>
<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="30" height="81">  
         <li><a href="#" class="navLink">Women</a></li>
<img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="30" height="81">
    <li><a href="#" class="navLink">Photography/Art</a></l



<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><p align="center"><img src='http://img547.imageshauuck.us/img547/3900/ehd.png' border='0'/></a><br>



  </ul>













</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should explain your changes, and try to post only the changed and relevant piece(s) of code. Explaining why the changes are necessary is even better.

Comment: I think this almost works, doesn't warrant a down vote. Your answer would be more welcome if it concentrated on the fix, no need to paste the entire code, keeps adding noise (irrelevant information). Here are some pointers: Using `!important` is for those who doesn't understand CSS specificity

Comment: Yes thankyou so much I've been looking for the solution for awhile now.

Comment: Fascinating that someone downvoted me within seconds of posting my answer.

Comment: Wasn't me, don't think it was warranted, but just posting a chunk of code makes it harder to understand what the fix was, even if it's right

Comment: @Taylor don't be discourage, downvote's are part of the culture here. Not everyone think on the same frequency. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I didn't realize the community here was so mean. And sorry it was my fault, I originally posted the full code thinking it would offer a better understanding. And thank you again Taylor.

Comment: If we are going to help out noobs, we need to be showing them the right way to start off. Not correcting things like letting them know to be using CSS to change colors and not inline in the element itself would be a start.

Comment: @patricksweeney: Agreed. Moving too fast for sure. I've added some inline comments.

Comment: @John Trust us, it's not. But like others have said, what you will want to do is to reduce your problem to its most basic form and state EXACTLY what you are having trouble with, not just throwing code up and saying it doesn't work. Let us know what you tried and what you expect to happen and it makes it easier for people to point you in the right direction. Good luck with the learning!

Comment: I wasn't really offended. Just surprised that it was so swift. =)
I use SO literally every day (several times).
@John: This is not a mean community. It's exceptionally helpful. It's just that a downvote without a comment as to why is uncommon.

Long live SO. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need simple CSS to change the way links look

Add the following CSS to your code

```
a, a:active, a:hover, a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
img{
border: 0px;
}
#logo {
margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}
#nav {
text-align: center;
list-style-type:none;
font-size: 36px;
font-family: helvetica neue;
font-weight: lighter;
margin: auto;
padding:0;
background: #000;
}
#nav li {
margin: 0px 20px;
display: inline;
}
#nav li a {

padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}
#nav li:hover{
background: #555;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
<img src="http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/2628/rf3h.png" alt="Vealed Logo">
<hr align="left" color="yellow" style="height: 4px;" width="90%">
</div>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photography/Art</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```